# Using LinkedList to Compute the Addition of Large Size of Numbers (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list

I wrote a program that computes the sum of n integers (randomly generated) in order to measure the time it took to calculate the sum of all values in an ArrayList and in a LinkedList in nanoseconds in a way I can compare time. The problem is that when I entered size 10^6 (1,000,000) for computation, it did not display  how long it took for LinkedList to calculate, only for ArrayList. I have more than 20 minutes waiting for it to display, but still no output. However, When I use smaller numbers for the size like 10^3 or 10^4, it works just fine. So, I was wondering if there is a limit when it comes to the size of a LinkedList. If so, what implementation using LinkedList can allow me to compute sum of values of size 10^6 ?

Comment: `List` is an interface. `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` are implementations of that interface. What are you asking?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The thing is that I want to compare the time that it takes to calculate the sum of 1,000,000 random numbers for each of the implementations(ArrayList and LinkedList). When I run the program and enter size 1,000,000 for computation, the program displays  only the time that it took to calculate 1,000,000 numbers in the ArrayList but it does not show the time it took to calculate the sum of the 1,000,0000 numbers in the LinkedList. However, when I enter smaller numbers such as 10^3 or 10^4. It works just fine and shows the time it took to compute the sum.

Comment: Post how you calculate the sum, and how you compute the time; possibly you need to wait longer for output.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I already have 30 minutes waiting for the output to show.  I don't think it is a reasonable time for this program to display the output.

Comment: What do you mean by random numbers ? Are you accessing the List in a random way using the indices ?

Comment: @NagakishoreSidde When adding numbers into the ArrayList or LinkedList, I write something like: "list.add((int) (100 * Math.random()));"

Comment: probably a bug in your code somewhere. without seeing your code i can only guess at the problems. time complexity may be too high and running time of your program increases drastically with input size. your code may be stuck in a loop somewhere. post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess what your code looks like.

```
  public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int LENGTH = 1000000;
          List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
          for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
              list.add((int) (100 * Math.random()));
          }

          // start timing
          int sum = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
             sum += list.get(i);
          }
          // stop timing and report
      }
  }
```

That will be fast.  The section that is being timed is likely to take less than 10th of a second. (And it will be faster still if the JVM has been properly "warmed up").

But if you *just* change `new ArrayList<>()` to `new LinkedList<>()` ... the timed section is likely to slow down by a factor of roughly 1 MILLION.  (I can predict this with a high degree of confidence that I will be right ...)

But why?

It is because of the `get(int)` method call!

- For an `ArrayList` the time taken to call `get(i)` is a small constant.  Maybe 10 to 20 hardware clock cycles, on a typical system where there are billions of clock cycles per second.  A few nanoseconds.
- For a `LinkedList` a `get(i)` call entails starting at the beginning of the list and skipping over `i` links.  One at a time.  The time taken is clearly proportional to the value of `i`.

In your test case, `i` ranges up to 1 million.  So in the `LinkedList` version, you do 1 million iterations of a loop where each iteration does (on average) 0.5 million steps.  (Actually, it may be 0.25 million because a `LinkedList` is doubly-linked, and according to @makoto the `get(i)` operation will traverse from the start or end of the list, whichever is nearer to `i`.)

---

In technical terms, the Big-O time complexity of `ArrayList` version of the test program is `O(N)`, and the `LinkedList` version is `O(N^2)` (i.e N squared ...) where `N` is the length of the list.

---

Interestingly ... if you rewrote the summing like this, the performance problem goes away in the `LinkedList` case:

```
          // start timing
          int sum = 0;
          for (Integer v : list) {
             sum += v;
          }
          // stop timing and report
```

... because now you are using an iterator and calling `next()` rather than `get(i)` to get the values.

Comment: No.  [`ArrayList` enjoys constant time access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and [`LinkedList` suffers from linear time access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) (due to its `get(int)` starting at whichever end is closest and it working its way forwards/backwards from there).

Comment: @Makoto - That is an implementation detail (that I want to check) but it doesn't change the overall explanation.

Comment: This is why I didn't downvote you.  Your answer is right; your Big-Oh is wrong.

Comment: @Makoto - The big-O is right.  The performance for N calls to get(i) where i is 0 to N-1 is `O(N^2)` for a linked list.  Even if you pick the shorter traversal (fwd versus bwd)

Comment: @Makoto - With the optimization, the number of links traversed on average in `get(i)` goes from 0.5 N to 0.25 N ... but that is still `O(N)`